# Date Validation in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services

I have a series of reports that are dependent on a to and from date.  I have set up parameters @Date1 and @Date2.  Prior to executing the query, I need to determine that Date1 is less than Date2.  This is important because the query is ...Where Date is between @Date1 and @Date2.  If @Date2 is less than @Date1 the query does not fail, it just returns no results.

I found code postings that say to add a function by going to Report Properties under the Report menu and place the code in the Code Tab.  I have looked at all over and cannot find this.

I am actually building the report in MS Visual Studio 2008.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is the question here just that you cant find where to enter custom code?

Comment: Yes that is exactly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2008 click **Report** -> **Report Properties**.

[image]

Click **Code** and add required code to **Custom Code** section.

[image]

Comment: Did this help at all? If not, please provide more information.